# In Notepad++ is it possible to search for lines that contain too many or too few instances of a particular delimiter?

Tags: notepad++, csv

One of our business partners is routinely sending us malformed CSV files. The file will contain 50,000 rows and several hundred of them have too many column delimiters.

Is there a way in Notepad++ to find all lines where the count of a particular delimiter is greater or less than a specified number, e.g. `count( | ) <> 16`

Comment: Definitely with some regex, but you'll need to wait for a regexpert to come along. My regex isn't up to spec i'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- Find what: `^[^|]*(?!(?:\|[^|\r\n]*){16}$)(?:\|[^|\r\n]*)*$`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  [^|]*             # 0 or more any character not pipe
  (?!               # start negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    (?:             # start non capture group
      \|            # a pipe
      [^|\r\n]*     # 0 or more non pipe, non linebreak
    ){16}           # end goup, must appear 16 times
    $               # end of line
  )                 # end lookahead
  (?:               # start non capture group
    \|              # a pipe
    [^|\r\n]*       # 0 or more non pipe, non linebreak
  )*                # end goup, may appear 0 or more times
$                   # ed of line
```

**Screen capture:**

For simplicity, I test for number of delimiter <> 3

[image]

Comment: A very helpful answer, thank you especially for the explanations.